# helm-projectile-recentf, Exclude Currently Open Buffer

Tags: helm-projectile

When I use helm-projectile-recentf, it shows the currently open buffer in the list. Any way to not have it do that?;)

Also, it seems to look at file modification, so if I just had a buffer open and didn't change it, it doesn't put it on the top of the list. Any way to make it do that?;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an option for exclusion, so I made a filter function, HTH.

```lisp
;; remove `projectile-project-root` from full path to match relative path in `projectile-recentf-files`
(defun strip-project-root (name)
  (replace-regexp-in-string (concat "^" (projectile-project-root)) "" name))

;; create a filter to return `projectile-recentf-files` - `buffer-list`
(defun my-projectile-recentf-files (list)
  "A filter to exclude currently open buffer from the original projectile-recentf-files."
  (let* ((buflist (mapcar 'strip-project-root (remove nil (mapcar 'buffer-file-name (buffer-list)))))
         (newlist list))
    (while buflist
      (setq newlist (remove (car buflist) newlist))
      (setq buflist (cdr buflist)))
    newlist))

;; put the filter after the original `projectile-recentf-files`
(eval-after-load 'projectile
  (advice-add 'projectile-recentf-files :filter-return #'my-projectile-recentf-files))
```

Comment: Thanks for this and sorry for taking ages to respond. This works perfectly;)